# How to pass Bind variable value to SQLplus using Batch file

Tags: oracle, batch-file, plsql, sqlplus

I want to pass a value to Sqlplus using batch file and store the output in excel.

```
SQL code:

Select :v_customerName||'|'||id||'|'||SUBMISSION_DATE||'|'||VALUE
from job_summary
```

In job_summary table, i have only 3 columns(id,date,value).I have to pass a customer name using batch file.

```
MY OUTPUT in Excel:
  |1|1-may-20|234
  |2|4-may-20|235
Output I want:
  abc|1|1-may-20|234
  abc|2|4-may-20|235
```

I don't now how to pase the value for customer in batch script.

```
My batch:
sqlplus hr/hr@ @Header.sql !customername!
```

Comment: Read this https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/literals-substitution-variables-and-bind-variables

Comment: By Using the Substitution variable , how i able to pass value from batch file and how can i add that value to the output file

Comment: Bind variable or substitution variable?

Answer (score 0):

`.SQL` script contents:

```
set colsep ';'
set ver off
set heading off
spool a.txt

select '&1', ename, job
from emp
where deptno = 10;

spool off
exit
```

Call it as follows; `Littlefoot` is parameter you want to see in the output file:

```
c:\Temp>sqlplus scott/tiger @p Littlefoot

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Uto Svi 12 07:14:38 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production


Littlefoot;CLARK     ;MANAGER
Littlefoot;KING      ;PRESIDENT
Littlefoot;MILLER    ;CLERK

Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

c:\Temp>
```

Result:

```
c:\Temp>type a.txt

Littlefoot;CLARK     ;MANAGER
Littlefoot;KING      ;PRESIDENT
Littlefoot;MILLER    ;CLERK


c:\Temp>
```

---

So:

- just *pass* the parameter
- reference it (in `.sql` script) with the `&` sign